# Getting error of Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'addAsessmentForm' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I created on validation file(AssessmentValidation) and used it in add and edit controller.
while inserting the data the validation is working while updating it getting above error.
this is my edit jsp. while update the data getting error

```
//JSP    
<form:form method="post" commandName="editAsessmentForm" action="editAsessment.action">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="bd-ct">     
            <div class="bd-ct-hd clearfix">
                <div class="hd-ct">
                    <fmt:message key="header.page.edit.Assessment"/>
                </div>          
            </div>              
            <div class="bd-ct-errors">
                <form:errors path="*" cssClass="errors" element="div"/>
            </div>      
            <div class="bd-sec">
                <div class="bd-sec-ct">
                    <table class="form-table" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <col width="50%"/>
                        <col width="50%"/>  
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="label">
                                    <form:label path="bodyLanguageScore">
                                            <fmt:message key="label.bodyLanguage"/><fmt:message key="label.1to5"/><fmt:message key="label.postfix"/>
                                    </form:label>
                                </td>
                                <td class="data" >
                                    <form:input path="bodyLanguageScore"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>                  
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>                  
        </div>      
    </fieldset>
</form:form>
```

Comment: Let's see the controller handler method that forwards to this jsp.

Comment: Also the error doesn't match the markup you've posted.

Comment: htis is my edit jsp page and my command name is editAsessmentForm

Comment: <form:form method="post" commandName="addAsessmentForm" action="addAsessment.action" >

Comment: You can edit your question to add more details.

Comment: I want to see where you add the model attribute `addAsessmentForm`.

Comment: above one is my add jsp page

Comment: in add controller    
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/addAsessment.action")
public class AddAsessmentController  extends   BaseFormController
{
 
 public static final String FORM_NAME = "addAsessmentForm";

Comment: So the validation is working for add, but not for edit? As Sotirios said, would you be able to update the body of the question and put the controller method for the edit? Your last comment above was for add, not edit.